# How do I view raw email headers in Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, headers

Is it possible to view raw / complete email headers in Outlook 2010?

In Outlook 2007 you could go to View > Options, or right click on a message, then select Options, and "Internet Headers" could be viewed.

However, in Outlook 2010 there is no "Options" in the context menu nor can I find it elsewhere.

Has it been removed altogether or moved (hidden) someplace else?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

"Internet Headers" is still there under **File->Properties**.

Open the message in a separate window first, otherwise **Properties** will not be available.

Copy and paste the headers to an editor in order to view them in a larger window.

See also: [How to view full email headers in Outlook 2010](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/theothersteve/how-to-view-full-email-headers-in-outlook-2010).

Comment: Actually, this doesn't help in the case of outlook being used with an exchange server.  You can get a delivery report, but this is the same information cut down to just times and vague statements like "transferred to another mail server.  This is as far as we can track it".  Actually, that is hiding details, preventing further tracking, where it would normally be possible.  Which mail server?  What did it respond with?  Where's the message ID that the other server filed the email under?  Outlook is essentially crippled in this respect.